# How can I display a nxn matrix depending on users input?

Tags: python, matrix, nested-for-loop

For a school task I need to display a nxn matrix depending on users input:
heres an example:

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

(users input: 5)

And here is my code until now:

```
    n = int(input("please enter a number: "))

    for i in range( 1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            print(0, end = " ")
        print('\n')
```

So it only displays zero in my matrix,
but how can I implement the one switching one position in each line?

Comment: I think googling will help a lot, faster than adding a question on SO which is a duplicate. Nevertheless you don't even have  a matrix per se (no array / np.array or any other data structure), just a nested loop. For what you are asking a transposed identity matrix from `numpy` would be helpful imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, try to find the relation or pattern happend when there is '1' in matrix, you will find that if (row_number + column_number = n - 1) then there is '1'
- `row=[]` you will make empty list to add the values of each row in it, **notice** that you will put `row=[]` inside `for row_number in range(n):` to make empty list after finish each row.
- `if row_number+column_number == n-1:` this is the pattern happens when there is '1', so if condition is true there is `1` will be appended in the `row`, and if condition is false there is `0` will be appended in the `row`.
- `print(*row)` i use `*` to unpack the elements of list

```
n = int(input("please enter a number: "))

for row_number in range(n):
    row = []
    for column_number in range(n):
        if row_number+column_number == n-1:
            row.append(1)
        else:
            row.append(0)
    print(*row)
```

**Output**

```
please enter a number: 5
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: [simplified](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P0/BVsGUiystv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNP04pLAQiK8suB8tEGsQpaCnkwkei6zFigqCGYX1CUmVeioQUU1vz/HwA)